How detailed should a research plan be in an assistant professor application?
When drafting a research plan for an assistant professor application, I’m struggling to find the right balance between providing enough detail and protecting my ideas. If the plan is too broad—similar to a literature review or like a research overview on a professor’s webpage—it may come across as unconvincing. However, if I include too many specifics, I worry about the risk of revealing key ideas.
Unlike grant applications, which are typically reviewed by a specialized panel, faculty applications are submitted to multiple institutions and reviewed by a broader audience. This makes the process feel riskier because even a high-level description could potentially give away important concepts—much like how the core of a paper can sometimes be inferred just from its title.
How can I strike the right balance between demonstrating the strength and innovation of my research while protecting my ideas? Should the approach be more similar to the way professors present their research on their webpages, or does a faculty application demand more technical detail?

If you don't trust the people at the places you apply to, why bother? Or do you imagine that places post job advertisements in order to steal the ideas of applicants?

@Buffy - that is rare but not unheard of.

Ok, I hope you don't mind if I'm a bit blunt.
Relax. Your ideas are not as important as you think - neither for other people nor for your career.
I'm serious.
Most professors have a lot more ideas than they have time to implement. They simply don't have time to take your ideas. And they have research agendas that don't fit precisely those ideas that they happen to see in some job application.
But just in case, what happens in the event that somebody actually does take one of your ideas and implements them on their own?
Then you're quite lucky. You intend to become a professor, so you have a lot more ideas than time to implement anyway (see the first sentence of the previous paragraph). So somebody saved you some time that you can spend on another idea from your list.
And even better: As they took your idea, it means that they are doing research that is closely related to yours. They will cite your papers. Use your results. Create opportunities for future collaborations. Increase the relevance of your research agenda. Convince other people that the topic is important (and that, hence, goverment money should be spent on it). Allow you to write sentences like "recently there is been a lot of interest in topic X". Allow you to claim in front of hiring committees that you're working in a highly active field. All of this means impact. That's the best thing you can achieve with your research and all you had to give for it was an idea, which you most likely have many more of. I call that a bargain.
And what about the credit? They implemented the idea, so don't they get the credit for the results? Yes, they do. And you get the credit for the other results - those that you had time to obtain because you did not pursue this specific idea since they did. You typically can't anticipate in detail which project will have better results or more impact, so it's kind of pointless to muse about things like "would I have achieved more if I had instead pursued the ideas that my colleagues took?"
So I suggest not to be very protective of your ideas. You will anyway build a huge backlog of ideas which are all very interesting and which you plan to pursue "at some point in the future". I ensure you, I'm the master of "surely going to implement this idea next summer" - and yet most of those ideas have been on my list for many summers and still no time to do it. It's the same for most people I know.
So focus on actually implementing ideas - don't try to hide or protect the ones that you plan to implement somewhen in the future.
Good luck!

Thanks for your answer. Maybe that depends on the field. In my field, from my observations of publications, most professors have no more than 5 important ideas published probably in their entire career. It is from rumor and happens to me (not necessarily important ones). The outcome of idea may be expected. It can be problematic in an early career.

@user207447: where are you applying for jobs?  In my field, it's true that most professors in India might have no more than 5 publishable ideas in their careers (and professors in Nigeria even fewer), but it's not true at research universities in the US or Europe.  (This isn't because Indians are somehow worse at research, but because US/Europe have better working conditions and therefore attract the Indian researchers who are good enough to have more than 5 ideas.)

@AlexanderWoo Thanks for your comment. To clarify, I meant important ideas. There are ways to be productive. But, filling a research plan with mediocre stuff doesn't make for a compelling application. I'd prefer not to discuss specific locations.

@user207447: While I don't know your field, I doubt that there are many fields where you can anticipate that an idea will turn out be important before implementing a considerable part of it. Regarding the research plan: I am under the impression that you're putting too much value on individual ideas here, too. The point about a research plan is to show an agenda or a big picture of what you're after. This is more than just an accumulation of key ideas.

The fantasy of being faculty with the reality don't match up. You soon find out many of your brilliant ideas are either wrong, can't be done in the environment you work in (infrastructure, student background and training, etc...), have previously been done, or you just get scooped by someone who did it better, or did it worse and undercuts you as you are working on them.

Going way back to my days on the job market, the only time I was scooped was when I interviewed for a job in Europe at a top global institution. All five candidates interviewed at the same time and we were all able to see the others' presentations (I'm told this is more common in the EU, it certainly is not in the US). I ended up in a different position in the US which was my choice of destination. Four years later I checked out of curiosity as to how the candidate who took the job was doing, and what do you know, their first and only publication is on one of the projects I proposed (their proposal had nothing to do with mine, not even conceptually overlapping as this was an "open" position).
This was an idea I had long abandoned in favor of a different program which better aligned with the job I took. I was happy to see it got published (in a top journal no less), but frankly did find it quite pathetic that they had to resort to taking my ideas.... but I never did it, so who cares, ideas are cheap and if you don't do them someone will at some point.
Otherwise, I've never been scooped by existing faculty at any place I have interviewed. When I was being poached and interviewed at other places, faculty interested in my work simply struck up collaborations.
Now as I sit on lots of hiring committees, what do I want to see in terms of detail, and why do I want to see it? I want to see that you can communicate your ideas clearly enough to make me confident that you can write a research proposal and be competitive for funding. I also want to see enough detail that I can ascertain as to whether or not our institution has the proposed infrastructure needed to support your work. i.e. will you compete for funding, and will you thrive in this environment?

Good story and good advice. I wonder how long it took the other person to pick up on your idea.
